# SQL - UNION, priority on the first select statement when doing order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I'm trying to print out the results from the "GermanDB" Database first, while also showing everything from the Boston DB that was not in the German database. Can this be done in one query?

My query (the bold part functions but does not order the way I want)

```
select * from (  
SELECT DISTINCT a.ProductRef  
FROM GERMANDB.dbo.LOCATIONS AS a INNER JOIN GERMANDB.dbo.ITEMS AS b ON a.ProductRef =   b.ProductRef   
WHERE b.ACTIVE=1  
) ta  
UNION select * from  
SELECT DISTINCT c.ProductRef  
FROM BOSTONDB.dbo.LOCATIONS AS c INNER JOIN BOSTONDB.dbo.ITEMS AS d ON c.ProductRef =   d.ProductRef   
WHERE c.ACTIVE=1 (c.ProductRef NOT IN   
(SELECT ProductRef FROM GERMANDB.dbo.ITEMS where ACTIVE=1))  
) tb  
order by ta.ProductRef** , tb.productRef
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add one field to signal the priority. Like this:

```
select *, 0 as Priority from (  
SELECT DISTINCT a.ProductRef  
FROM GERMANDB.dbo.LOCATIONS AS a INNER JOIN GERMANDB.dbo.ITEMS AS b ON a.ProductRef =   b.ProductRef   
WHERE b.ACTIVE=1  
) ta  
UNION select *, 1 as Priority from  
SELECT DISTINCT c.ProductRef  
FROM BOSTONDB.dbo.LOCATIONS AS c INNER JOIN BOSTONDB.dbo.ITEMS AS d ON c.ProductRef =   d.ProductRef   
WHERE c.ACTIVE=1 (c.ProductRef NOT IN   
(SELECT ProductRef FROM GERMANDB.dbo.ITEMS where ACTIVE=1))  
) tb  
order by Priority, ProductRef
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it does not distinct records, because of different (0 and 1) values for new Priority column